# Asymptotic notation - Algorithm to determine complexity class

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I´m working on my bachelor thesis about Asymptotic notation. I have inputs for two functions and I need to find point "n0" [like on this picture (point n)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzMOE.png) to determine complexity class and draw graph.

Any ideas about an algorithm? Any relevant link is also welcome.

Comment: In the simplest form, are you just trying to find the intercept between two functions?

Comment: Not exactly... maybe LAST intercept could help